# How to design React Admin Panel(Dashboard)?

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React.js, I want to create a Dashboard for getting good understanding of react i tried react-admin panel but not getting a good understanding of it. I wanna know how should i start? ,using bootstarp from scratch will it beneficial? can you guys suggest some good content regarding that. thanks in advance

Comment: if you are new to react you cant understand how react admin work, i suggest you to learn more from react redux redux-saga hooks... and then retry to learn react-admin again

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use antd to start making admin panel. here is the [link](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) as antd provide lots of custom components help you to speed up your work. also you can select layout from [here](https://ant.design/components/layout) according to your requirement. every component are easy to use just you have to pass the props